# How do I load Ubuntu using Netboot?

Tags: system-installation

I've been reading through the different options and through the wiki but was wondering which option would be the best for me? I have a tower that was running Windows XP from a friend, and want to load Ubuntu onto it.

The boot options are Network Boot, Floppy, CD-ROM, Hard Drive. No USB option. Phoenix - AwardBios Core Version V6.0, BIOS Revision 3.11 5/17/2004

256 mb pc2700

I have my desktop running Ubuntu, but need to know how to get Ubuntu onto that tower. Which is my best option, and what do I download to get it set up properly? Any advice towards a Netboot would be amazing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did the PC have a working CD-Drive?

Comment: Yes, but there is no where around me locally to buy rw cd. I know I can go that route, but I'm trying to see if I can actually use the Netboot option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something called PLOP Linux.  It will allow you to boot from a USB when the BIOS does not support it.  It's tiny, which is a plus for PXE booting.  Here is a step by step on how to set it up.  Goodluck!  http://www.plop.at/en/ploplinux/networkboot-linux.html